# Controller Stuck at component.get("v.recordId")

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to get case record Id using lightning button but my controller is not moving forward from this line -component.get("v.recordId") 
I don't know what is wrong.

Please help:

This my component

```
<aura:component controller="EmailSendController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">  

<lightning:button label="Send Notification" title="Send Notification" onclick="{!c.sendMail}"/>
```

This is my controller

```
({
sendMail: function(component, event, helper) {  
    console.log("Button Clicked--");
    var caseID = component.get("v.recordId"); 
    Console.log("CaseID--"+ component.get("v.recordId") );
    var action = component.get("c.sendMailMethod");
    action.setParams({
     "caseId" : caseID
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        Console.log("Response"+response.getState());
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            //var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();

        }

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

},
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. 2nd `Console` should be lowercase, I suspect it throws an error about undefined object.

You can use your browsers JS console (in Chrome Ctrl+Shift+J) to inspect such errors. It also helps to go to Setup -> Debug Mode and add your user in there. SF will get bit slower but you'll see more human-readable code and errors instead of optimised, minified mess.

If it still throws errors - use console to check what error exactly and edit your question?

P.S. change it in callback handler too

Comment: Glad I could help :)